# Layouts for news-articles in the news-extension for TYPO3

Tags: typo3, tx-news

While it is possible to choose and edit layout variants for the plugin and so for e.g. list views it seems impossible to have a choice of layout variants for a single news article, which then could be rendered differently in the list or single view. As it was possible with rgnewsimg ...
Any ideas how something like this could be achieved?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This would really be a nice function. On your own you can extend news and add a select field to news records to configure the detail layout. If you extend the extension well, you can access this field in fluid template then.

Another solutation would be using the categories for changing the detail view. You could add categories like "Style1" or "Style2" and then access the selection in fluid. It is possible like this, but its quite dirty.

Answer (score 0):

And perfect would be a ViewHelper to allow for conditions in fluid regarding the aspect ratio of the first image, ie. to control the news article's layout depending on the used image:

if image's aspect ratio < 1 (= Portrait) ...

Unfortunately I can't code that ...